# Error trying to upload an image to CloudKit using Swift3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm running into a compiler error when using the following code:

```
func saveImageToDisk() {

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)!
    let fileName = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image.png")
    imageData.writeToFile(fileName, atomically: true)

}
```

The error is: `Value of type 'Data' has no member 'writeToFile'`

Could this be a compiler error, or something I'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SE-0005](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md) proposed a better translation of Objective-C APIs into Swift and that affected NSData (or just Data now). Instead of `writeToFile` you'll have to use `write(to:options:)` (or even just `write(to:)`). [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779858-write) is the documentation for the updated method.

Comment: Thanks again. In the light of day, I better understood your answer, and it solves this issue.